# Does setting sonar.timemachine.period1 from config or command line work?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am attempting to set the leak period in SonarQube 5.6.5 using [Sonar Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) with a properties file or command line argument, but I am having no success.

I would like to set the `sonar.timemachine.period1` property to a specific version, e.g., `1.0.0`, as is mentinoned in solution 2 (using `sonar-project.properties`) or solution 3 (using command line paramter, e.g., `-Dsonar.timemachine.period1=1.0.0`) of the accepted answer for [Sonar runner, seeonly newly introduced issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702291/sonar-runner-seeonly-newly-introduced-issues).

Here is the scenario that reproduces my issue.

1. Run analysis with `sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0`.
2. Run analysis with `sonar.projectVersion=2.0.0` and `sonar.timemachine.period1=1.0.0`.
3. Run analysis with `sonar.projectVersion=3.0.0` and `sonar.timemachine.period1=1.0.0`.

After the second and third analysis I would expect the leak period to be "since `1.0.0`" (which is the behavior if I manually set the leak period in the SonarQube admin section to `1.0.0`).  Instead, for the third analysis the leak period is being set to `2.0.0`.

What am I missing?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `sonar.timemachine.period1` via 'normal' property is not sufficient, you will need to set properties via REST Api - note you'll need admin rights.
Had the same problem when using the Sonarqube Ant Task and created a macrodef for that purpose.
See :
[Sonarqube Wep API documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392170#WebService/api/properties-CreateorUpdateaProperty)
[Sonarqube set leak period to specific version other than previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743916)

Comment: FYI, there's an open feature request at https://community.sonarsource.com/t/make-sonar-leak-period-an-analysis-parameter/13798 to support setting the leak period on a per-scan basis.

Answer (score 1):

Rebse is correct, you must use the API to set the `sonar.timemachine.period1` property.  I'm not using Ant.  I used a `curl` command from Bamboo.

```
curl
-X POST 
-u MY_USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD 
-d resource=MY_PROJECT_KEY
-d id=sonar.timemachine.period1 
-d value=1.0.0
http://localhost:9000/api/properties
```

Comment: You may create a usertoken - See My Account / security - and use -u usertoken: instead of username:password,  means usertoken followed by separator: and empty password.